# SQL To Track Rules

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using MS SQL Server and have a stored procedure where I evaluate transactions based on certain rules and mark each row as eligible or not based on these rules. For example, a transaction from prior year is ineligible, certain products may not be eligible.

I also want to record the reason why the transaction is ineligible. For example, from prior year, ineligible product, etc. I have a table that lists all ineligibility codes.

I apply rules sequentially and record the first reason for ineligibility in the field eligCode defined as int.

But I cannot seem to figure out how to code this in the stored procedure. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into the CASE statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you head start:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo.YourSprocName]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE 
            WHEN datepart(year, transaction_date) = datepart(year, getdate()) - 1 --if transaction_date year = previous year
                THEN 'Ineligible'
            WHEN product_type = < something > -- non eligible products
                THEN 'Non-eligible'
            ELSE 'Eligible'
            END AS transaction_status
        ,CASE 
            WHEN ineligibility_code = 1 -- assuming 1 is one of the ineligbility code
                THEN 'Bad transaction'
            ELSE 'Unknown'
            END AS ineligibilty_reason_desc
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE yourColumn = < condition >
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @eligCode as int
declare @TransID as int

....
select  @TransID = NNN -- some value declared above
        @eligCode = CASE 
                    WHEN YEAR(TRANSACTION_DATE) < YEAR(getdate()) THEN 1
                    WHEN [CONDITION2] THEN 2
                    WHEN [CONDITION3] THEN 3
                    WHEN [CONDITION4] THEN 4
                    ELSE 0
                END
...
Insert into LOG_TABLE (Transaction_ID, eligCode) values (@TransID, @eligCode)
```